# If app is waiting for review, how can I create an ad hoc version?

Tags: xcode4, app-store-connect, ad-hoc-distribution

I just submitted my app, and now it's "waiting for review"... I want to send someone on my test team the latest version using Ad Hoc distribution.  However, I keep getting this error:

[image]

while attempting to login to iTunes Connect during validation.  Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using a service like http://www.testflightapp.com. You can use the same IPA you submitted to the app store with the same license and distribute it to anyone via an email address. They have to install software but it works great.

**Update**: This answer from Spokane-Dude (questioner)

`You don't need to validate the application to use ad hoc distribution. You archive it, choose "Distribute...", and then choose the middle radio button "Save for Enterprise or Ad Hoc Deployment". You choose a profile, click through any keychain prompts, and get a save dialog.`

Comment: I use TestFlight already... in order to create the .ipa, you have to validate the archive and then it asks what you want to do with it.  At that point, you can choose Ad Hoc, App Store or Enterprise... I can't get past the iTunes Connect signin.

Comment: Are you selecting AppStore?

Comment: If you cant connect and you are using AdHoc then its likely because your Certificate wasnt created for AD-Hoc. It was created for App Store Distribution

Comment: Never get that far... the problem is shown in the image in the question above... will not logon to iTunes Connect unless app is "ready for upload"...

Comment: No, certificate and profiles are correct... I distribute this app Ad Hoc all the time... just won't let me do it now...

Comment: create another one and fake it out :)

Comment: is there a way to create the .ipa without going through validation?

Comment: Spokane, I am at work right now but I will look at TestFlight tonight on my mac. Something is wrong because I have submitted TestFlights all day long without a Waiting for Upload app on the appstore

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33395/discussion-between-logixologist-and-spokane-dude). Grrrr blocked from work. OK I will log on tonight when I get home

Comment: Here's the answer:
You don't need to validate the application to use ad hoc distribution.  You archive it, choose "Distribute...", and then choose the middle radio button "Save for Enterprise or Ad Hoc Deployment".  You choose a profile, click through any keychain prompts, and get a save dialog.

Comment: I added your last comment to the answer.